# RHEL UBI8.6-FIPS: yum install aide -> No match for argument: aide

Tags: yum, aide, stig

BLUF:
I want to install AIDE via package manager but yum is not able to find the rpm

SYSTEM SETUP:
Docker image/container of RHEL UBI8.6-FIPS running on Ubuntu 20.04 DISA-STIG compliant FIPS enabled HOST.  AppStream repo is enabled.

DISCLAIMER:
I am an everyday Ubuntu user - not RHEL - so please feel free to call me an idiot for missing something.

STEPS I PERFORMED:
I am following the [RHEL Security Hardening Manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/pdf/security_hardening/red_hat_enterprise_linux-8-security_hardening-en-us.pdf) and DISA-STIG checklist.  I verified that AIDE is supposed to be in the AppStream by checking the [manifest](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/package_manifest/index).

1. Verified AppStream is enabled:

```bash
[root@a1100622ac26 aide-0.17.4]# yum repolist
repo id                                                                repo name
ubi-8-appstream-rpms                                                   Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStream
ubi-8-baseos-rpms                                                      Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS
ubi-8-codeready-builder-rpms                                           Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder
```

2. Checked the yum repo to ensure the URI is correct:

```bash
[root@a1100622ac26 scripts]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/ubi.repo 
[ubi-8-baseos-rpms]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/baseos/os
enabled = 1
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1

[ubi-8-baseos-debug-rpms]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (Debug RPMs) - BaseOS
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/baseos/debug
enabled = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1

[ubi-8-baseos-source]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (Source RPMs) - BaseOS
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/baseos/source/SRPMS
enabled = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1

[ubi-8-appstream-rpms]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStream
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/appstream/os
enabled = 1
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1

[ubi-8-appstream-debug-rpms]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (Debug RPMs) - AppStream
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/appstream/debug
enabled = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1

[ubi-8-appstream-source]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (Source RPMs) - AppStream
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/appstream/source/SRPMS
enabled = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1

[ubi-8-codeready-builder-rpms]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/codeready-builder/os
enabled = 1
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1

[ubi-8-codeready-builder]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/codeready-builder/os
enabled = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1


[ubi-8-codeready-builder-debug-rpms]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (Debug RPMs) - CodeReady Builder
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/codeready-builder/debug
enabled = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1

[ubi-8-codeready-builder-source]
name = Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (Source RPMs) - CodeReady Builder
baseurl = https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/$basearch/codeready-builder/source/SRPMS
enabled = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
gpgcheck = 1
```

3. Updated yum:

```bash
[root@a1100622ac26 scripts]# yum update
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS                                                                                            4.9 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStream                                                                                         2.2 MB/s | 3.2 MB     00:01    
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder                                                                                 5.6 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00    
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

4. Attempted to install AIDE:

```bash
[root@a1100622ac26 aide-0.17.4]# yum install aide
Last metadata expiration check: 0:48:42 ago on Wed Jan 25 08:01:40 2023.
No match for argument: aide
Error: Unable to find a match: aide
```

5. Traveled to the [AppStream URI](https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/x86_64/appstream/os/Packages/a/) to manually search for the aide rpm using my browser.  The aide rpm was not present.
6. Traveled to the [AIDE GitHub Pages](https://aide.github.io/) and they claim the proper way to install is via AppStream using yum.

I'm not trying to perform a manual install of AIDE because of dependencies and installation will be performed within a Dockerfile so package manager is preferred.  Any rpms obtained online will have to be from a trusted source and one of the STIG requirements require the developer to maintain and provide updates (pretty much requiring a package manager for updates).  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to programming or software development? Better ask at https://superuser.com/

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko stackoverflow's homepage (when you aren't logged in) claims to be for system administration as well.  I believe the forum may have started for programming or software development, but has expanded it's scope over the years.  Thank you for your suggestion and I make a post on that site as well.

Comment: didn't mean to offend you... Did just mean that from my POV you'll get faster/better answers at SuperUser since it's specialized on that kind of questions, rather than on StackOverflow where mostly coders are concentrated, not administrators.